# Return Excel Row in Word Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have ContentControl drop down box in Word. Once I select an item from a Drop Down list I want to search for that in an Excel document and set the row number equal to a variable.
The code below is what I tried but the Columns("G:G").Find part says its not defined.

```
Sub findsomething(curRow) 
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rownumber As Long

    curPath = ActiveDocument.path & "\" 
    Call Set_Variable(curPath) 
    StrWkShtNm = "Chapters"

    If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then   
        MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub 
    End If

    Set rng = Columns("G:G").Find(what:=curRow)
    rownumber = rng.Row
    MsgBox rownumber
    ' Release Excel object memory 
    Set xlWkBk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Range("G:G")` instead. Or to stick with `Columns`, `Columns(7)`

Answer (score 0):

While using more than one MS Office application it is a good idea to specify which application you are targeting:

```
 Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what ended up working. you set me on the right track with referencing Excel.

```
Sub findsomething(curRow)
Dim rng As Long
Dim rownumber As Long

curPath = ActiveDocument.path & "\"
Call Set_Variable(curPath)
StrWkShtNm = "Chapters"
MsgBox "curRow = " & curRow

If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If

With xlApp
  .Visible = False
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=StrWkBkNm, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
  With xlWkBk
    With .Worksheets(StrWkShtNm)
        rng = .Range("G:G").Find(what:=curRow)
        MsgBox rng
    End With
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With


' Release Excel object memory
Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```